# How to overwrite Material UI classes via parameters

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to overwrite the color of the delete icon of a chip via parameter from the parent. The styles need to be set dynamically. The parameter holds the styles as an object. Normally the delete-icon would be styled [like here](https://codesandbox.io/s/o734k18n26). I cannot use a style-attribute to reach the delete icon. The attempt below does not work.

```
const styles = { deleteIcon: { color: 'white'}};

export const ChipsCustom = (styles) => {

  const ele = (data, classes) => {

    return (
      <Chip
        classes={{
          deleteIcon: classes.deleteIcon,
        }}
      />
    );
  };
  return withStyles(styles)(ele);
};
```

Comment: what's wrong with codesandbox implementation?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor How can I change the color from outside the component? e.g. to green

Comment: You mean parent component is sending color as props ? and you don't want to use const styles ? right ?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor yes! exactly

Comment: I gave an explanation below you can ask further question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working codesandbox where classes are passed down to the children as props:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nr0r197zjm

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import FaceIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Face";
import DoneIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Done";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  chip: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    color: "blue",
    "&:hover": {
      background: "#ff9814"
    }
  },
  deleteIcon: {
    color: "green"
  }
});

function handleDelete() {
  alert("You clicked the delete icon."); // eslint-disable-line no-alert
}

function handleClick() {
  alert("You clicked the Chip."); // eslint-disable-line no-alert
}

//Parent Component

function CustomChips(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return <MyChip classes={classes} />;
}

//Child Component

function MyChip(props) {
  const { classes } = props; //props are coming from parent

  console.log(classes);
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Chip
        label="Deletable Chip"
        onDelete={handleDelete}
        classes={{
          root: classes.chip,
          deleteIcon: classes.deleteIcon
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

CustomChips.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomChips);
```